# Error while trying to export logins from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: migration, sql-server-2000, logins

I'm trying to migrate logins from an instance in SQL 2000 to a destination instance in SQL 2005.

I've used revlogin before as explained here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246133

(I'm using the "Method 2" as explained in the article)

The problem is that while trying to create the sp_hexadecimal stored procedure (used by sp_help_revlogin_2000_to_2005) I get the following error:

```
USE master 
GO 
IF OBJECT_ID ('sp_hexadecimal') IS NOT NULL 
DROP PROCEDURE sp_hexadecimal 
GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_hexadecimal 
@binvalue varbinary(256), 
@hexvalue varchar(256) OUTPUT 
AS 
DECLARE @charvalue varchar(256) 
DECLARE @i int 
DECLARE @length int 
DECLARE @hexstring char(16) 
SELECT @charvalue = '0x' 
SELECT @i = 1 
SELECT @length = DATALENGTH (@binvalue) 
SELECT @hexstring = '0123456789ABCDEF' 
WHILE (@i <= @length) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @tempint int 
DECLARE @firstint int 
DECLARE @secondint int 
SELECT @tempint = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@binvalue,@i,1)) 
SELECT @firstint = FLOOR(@tempint/16) 
SELECT @secondint = @tempint - (@firstint*16) 
SELECT @charvalue = @charvalue + 
SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @firstint+1, 1) + 
SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @secondint+1, 1) 
SELECT @i = @i + 1 
END 
SELECT @hexvalue = @charvalue 
GO 


Msg 134, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_hexadecimal, Line 26
The variable name '@binvalue' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
```

This is super weird since the same SP works in other instances.

I'm leaning to believe that this is related to the SQL version I'm working on:

```
Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2301
Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

The script works well in a:

```
Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2066 (Intel X86)
Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Is there a workaround?

I found some references to this issue on the Web but they are all inconclusive.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic309704-5-1.aspx
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/55b9a6c6-2e03-42dd-bcfc-31f487171b73/variable-already-declared-error-when-adding-stored-procedure?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Thanks!

Comment: I made some further testing and this does not seems to be related to the instance's version numnber.

Comment: I tried this on a 8.00.2305 and works OK, then went back to the instance where the error is manifesting and upgraded it to 2305 and after upgrading the error persists.

Comment: is there a lot of logins ? Maybe you should do this in an not automated way

Comment: Sadly there a few hundreds of them... but the most important thing is that I need to preserve all passwords.

Comment: I'm now looking into https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools with a bit of luck I may be able to use the Export-SQLLogins function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dealing with this error quite a lot I was not able to find a way to make it work, since support for SQL2000 is no longer available I ended up using dbatools (an awesome PowerShell module): github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools

dbatools has a function called Export-SqlLogin which does exactly what I needed: script all logins with sid, password, server role, default db, etc.

I highly recommend looking into this PowerShell module.

Answer (score 0):

Not very usefull, but I have tested it on my sql server 2000 test instance ; version is :

[image]

Then copy and start all the code from "Method2" (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246133), Everything ran fine :

[image]

Comment: Yep... this is the same result that I'm getting from the servers in which the script executes properly.